# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am unable to use geckodriver in selenium. It is showing me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/E/INSURANCE/Data.py", line 13, in <module>

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\intel\Downloads\geckodriver.exe')

  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()

  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running

raise WebDriverException(
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\intel\Downloads\geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595
```

**Any help would be appreciated...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable runtime, it might fix your problem.

Source: [Geckodriver issue from bugtracker](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1672).